# Brushed Motor with Wires - Where to put BEMF diode (EMI)?

Tags: dc-motor, emc, emi-filtering

I'm designing a system that drives brushed motors with PWM, where the motor and the PCB with the drive circuitry is separated by wires. Thinking about the EMI situation, would it be better to put the diode (or diode+resistor) as close to the motor as possible (i.e. on the terminals themselves), vs putting it on the PCB?

[image]

Additionally, any good app-notes on brushed motor EMI redution would be appreciated in the comments. Current plan is to have twisted wires, ferrites on both ends, 100pF capacitor directly across motor terminals, and possibly changing diode to diode+resistor.

Comment: Putting it next to the MOSFET also protects the MOSFET from the voltage spike due to wire inductance. Putting it next to the motor does not (but might reduce EMI since the motor current flows in a tighter loop),

Comment: @DKNguyen what about having both? diodes are pretty cheap so thats not really an issue

Comment: That works too. Although it may be redundant with the cap close to the motor already, but the the cap is limited in its ability to dampen. It's faster to turn on since it never really ever turns off, but will charge up whereas the diode takes time to turn on but clamps. Why would you add a resistor to the diode? If anything turn the cap into an RC snubber.

Comment: @DKNguyen I've seen some suggestion about adding a resistor in order to decrease the decay time. Since the maximum current will be defined already, you can size the resistor so that the maximum voltage is still within the spec of all of your components, but it will dissapate the EMF much faster. It's not actually clear to me though if that's a good thing for PWM (in fact it probably isnt, depending on the PWM timescale)

Comment: The resistor does other things too like damp LC oscillations and reduces power dissipation in the cap.

Answer (score 0):

You can attenuate dV/dt arc noise in a brush motor during commutation when the impedance is higher  with an RC snubber as Ic=CdV/dt is limited by R, But with R=0 the current increases in the loop step voltage as it would with a PWM BLDC.

The bigger noise is differential fields from the wire loop area which would be minimized with twisted-pair or preferably suitable shielded cable.  Then with different grounds, there are large common-mode noise fields, which may be attenuated with a CM choke much higher impedance (xxx ohms)  in the spectrum of dominant noise. This is often done with large lossy ferrite or good CM chokes but must be high inductance and low resistance.

Answer (score 0):

You put the diode next to the motor:.
The inductance of the wire will reduce the rise times of currents, the diode will clamp faster if placed next to the motor

The wire will also have a potential to radiate emf if the currents have to go to the PCB with the low side switch, keep the back emf currents on the motor board by leaving the diode on the motor board